# Sprite Not Tiling Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Even though I set my texture's mesh type to full rect and my sprite renderer's Draw Mode to tiled, my sprite does not tile. Instead, it stretches.

[Sprite Renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu0lE.png)

[Texture Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjjf0.png)

I tried to adjust all the settings in the renderer. However, it still stretched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a tile map. It was way easier and took about 30 seconds.